# List with sparse data consumes less memory then the same data as numpy array

Tags: python, memory, numpy, sparse-array

I am working with very high dimensional vectors for machine learning and was thinking about using numpy to reduce the amount of memory used. I run a quick test to see how much memory I could save using numpy (1)(3):

*Standard list*

```
import random
random.seed(0)
vector = [random.random() for i in xrange(2**27)]
```

*Numpy array*

```
import numpy
import random
random.seed(0)
vector = numpy.fromiter((random.random() for i in xrange(2**27)), dtype=float)
```

*Memory usage (2)*

```
Numpy array: 1054 MB
Standard list: 2594 MB
```

**Just like I expected.**

By allocing a continues block of memory with native floats numpy only consumes about half of the memory the standard list is using.

Because I know my data is pretty spare, I did the same test with sparse data.

*Standard list*

```
import random
random.seed(0)
vector = [random.random() if random.random() < 0.00001 else 0.0 for i in xrange(2 ** 27)]
```

*Numpy array*

```
from numpy import fromiter
from random import random
random.seed(0)
vector = numpy.fromiter((random.random() if random.random() < 0.00001 else 0.0 for i in xrange(2 ** 27)), dtype=float)
```

*Memory usage (2)*

```
Numpy array: 1054 MB
Standard list: 529 MB
```

**Now all of the sudden, the python list uses half the amount of memory the numpy array uses! Why?**

One thing I could think of is that python dynamically switches to a dict representation when it detects that it contains very sparse data. Checking this could potentially add a lot of extra run-time overhead so I don't really think that this is going on.

Notes

1. I started a fresh new python shell for every test.
2. Memory measured with htop.
3. Run on 32bit Debian.

Comment: Is this on a 32 bit or a 64 bit system? I suspect that the pointers to 0 in the Python list are smaller than the numpy floats.

Comment: `0` literal is an integer, so your list is built mostly from ints, where in numpy array you have all floats. What is more, small integers (-5..255) are interned, so all those zeros in the list point to the same object. Try using `0.0` and see if there is a difference.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Tests are run on 32bits Debian. Updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @m.wasowski Changed the literal int zero to a float. Same results. Updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Python list is just an array of references (pointers) to Python objects. In CPython (the usual Python implementation) a list gets slightly over-allocated to make expansion more efficient, but it *never* gets converted to a dict. See the source code for further details: [List object implementation](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listobject.c)

In the sparse version of the list, you have a lot of pointers to a single `int` 0 object. Those pointers take up 32 bits = 4 bytes, but your numpy floats are certainly larger, probably 64 bits.

FWIW, to make the sparse list / array tests more accurate you should call `random.seed(some_const)` with the same seed in both versions so that you get the same number of zeroes in both the Python list and the numpy array.

Comment: Numpy indeed defaults to 64bits floats, forcing them to 32bits resulted in a comparable in size array. Thanks!